# How to realize scalable image over image layout?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I want to show an icon in the top right corner of an image. Also, it should be slightly offset. And finally, the combination of both should be scalable, so that doubling the total width results in the image as well as the icon having thwice the original width. Of course, the aspect ration should be kept so that the height doubles as well.

As the description of that actually simple problem is quite complex, here's an artful drawing illustrating the subject :)

[image]

So, let's say I have a `RecyclerView` with a `GridLayout` where each image tile has a width of 200dp. Then, the gray area should have a width and height of 200dp, the orange icon has a width and height of 50dp, the offset of the icon to the blue image's border is 25dp and so on.

And if I decide to double the number of columns in my `GridLayout`, the gray area has a width and height of 100dp etc.

**Here's what I tried so far:**

I started out with a `FrameLayout` which works fine for the simplest cases but becomas problematic as soon you want to specify dimensions with percentages.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="50dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/blueShip200x200" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|end"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/new50x50" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Then, I learned about the `PercentFrameLayout` that has been introduced with the support library, recently - and has already been deprecated: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentFrameLayout.html

So now the advice is to use `ConstraintLayout` instead (see link above) where you can use helper guidelines that allow you to define their position with percentages.

Fortunately, the docs give an example how to replace the `PercentFrameLayout` which works great if the gray box has a fixed width and height:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/left_image_guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".25" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/right_image_guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".75" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/top_image_guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".25" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/bottom_image_guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".75" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/bottom_image_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/left_image_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/right_image_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/top_image_guideline"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/blueShip200x200" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/left_icon_guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".625" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/right_icon_guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".875" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/top_icon_guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".125" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/bottom_icon_guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".375" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/bottom_icon_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/left_icon_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/right_icon_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/top_icon_guideline"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/new50x50" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

But if you do not specifiy fixed dimensions... it doesn't.

Adapting the following lines from the `FrameLayout` example (`layout_width`, `layout_height`, `adjustViewBounds`) results in the `ConstraintLayout` getting a height of 0.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/bottom_image_guideline"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/left_image_guideline"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/right_image_guideline"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/top_image_guideline"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/blueShip200x200" />
```

I hope it's possible to solve this problem non-programmatically with some changes to the layout file. Basically, it's just `adjustViewBounds` that is not working with the `ImageView`'s width and height set to `match_constraint` (0dp).

Also, if possible, I'd like to stick with `ConstraintLayout`. Maybe one can work around the problem using `LinearLayout`s with `Space`s and `layout_weight` - I haven't tried that yet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you can create a layout using a constraint layout.

first you split the layout into 5x5 using some views as a guide.
the key is to use the horizontal and vertical weights.

[image]

```
<!--GUIDE LINE-->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/guide_1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/primary_light"
    android:text="25%"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="25"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guide_2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guide_2"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="25" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/guide_2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/primary_light"
    android:text="37.5%"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guide_1"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="37.5"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guide_1"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/guide_3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guide_3"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="37.5" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/guide_3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/primary_light"
    android:text="12.5%"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guide_2"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="12.5"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guide_2"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/guide_4"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guide_4"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="12.5" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/guide_4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/primary_light"
    android:text="12.5%"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guide_3"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="12.5"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guide_3"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/guide_5"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guide_5"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="12.5" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/guide_5"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/primary_light"
    android:text="12.5%"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guide_4"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="12.5"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/guide_4"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="12.5" />
```

after you create the guide, you can put the images you want with the guide line...

[image]

the two views would be something like the following.

```
<TextView
    android:text="MAIN ICON"
    android:textColor="@color/icons"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="60sp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guide_2"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guide_2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guide_3"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/guide_3"
    android:background="@color/primary"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guide_4"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/guide_4"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guide_3"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/guide_3"
    android:background="@color/accent"
    android:text="NEW"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:textColor="@color/icons"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

FIxing dimension of small image will help you attain that kind of UI. Please look into code below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="25dp"
        android:paddingRight="25dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:id="@+id/image"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/blue200" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/image"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/image"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/new50x50" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to accomplish can be done with some recent additions to `ConstraintLayout`. I did the following with version 1.1.0-beta3. See the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html).

With later releases of `ConstrainLayout`, we can now specify the width and height of a view as a percentage of the containing view's width/height. The blue box is sized at 50% of the width/height of the gray area and centered.

The orange box is sized at 25% of the container's width and height. It is centered on the top right corner of the blue box by setting its start and end sides to the end of the blue box and its top and bottom to the top.

The layout will accommodate all sizes but, as you mention, the aspect ratios must be respected.

[image]

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/boat"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/boat"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.5" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/new_square"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/boat"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/boat"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.25"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/boat"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/boat"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0..25" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here are the images I used:

[image]
[image]